# Trigonometry and Solve

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find values ​​for "x" using `Solve`, but I do not think it's the best solution.
What is the most appropriate function to calculate this?

```
Solve[Tan[α] == a/x && Tan[2 α] == (a + 5)/x && x^2 + (a + 5)^2 == 10^2, {x, a}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Solve[Tan[\[Alpha]] == a/x && Tan[2 \[Alpha]] == (a + 5)/x && 
  x^2 + (a + 5)^2 == 100 && 0 < \[Alpha] < Pi/4 && 0 < a < 10 && 
  0 < x < 10, {x, a, \[Alpha]}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the comments of [Feyre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132892/trigonometry-and-solve/132897#comment358557_132892)

```
values={a,x,α}/.Solve[Tan[α]==a/x&&Tan[2 α]==(a+5)/x&&x^2+(a+5)^2==100&&0<α<Pi/2&&0<a<10&&0<x<10,{x,a,α}]//N;
a=values[[1,1]]
x=values[[1,2]]
α=values[[1,3]]
```

> a=3
>   x=6
>   α=0.463648 rad

Comment: You can do `{a,x,α}={a,x,α}/.Solve[....]`, or `Solve[....] /. Rule -> Set`, or `Solve[....] /. Rule -> Equal` for a display.

Comment: @corey979 to add to your comment, you could use `Reduce` instead of `Solve` in this case.

Comment: @LCarvalho "for a display"